# How can I include one expression in another expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a DateRange class that I'd like to apply to an IQueryable as a where predicate, automatically using the begin and end dates and automatically using an open or closed interval.

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool BeginInclusive { get; set; }
    public bool EndInclusive { get; set; }

    public DateRange()
    {
        BeginInclusive = true;
        EndInclusive = false;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Apply<T>( IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T,DateTime>> dateField )
    {
        var result = source;
        if (BeginDate.HasValue)
        {
            if (BeginInclusive)
                result = result.Where( x => dateField >= BeginDate ); //does not compile
            else
                result = result.Where( x => dateField > BeginDate ); //does not compile
        }
        if (EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            if (EndInclusive)
                result = result.Where( x => dateField <= EndDate ); //does not compile
            else
                result = result.Where( x => dateField < EndDate ); //does not compile
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I want to call it like this, DateField is any DateTime property of T.

```
DateRange d;
IQueryable<T> q;
q = d.Apply( q, x => x.DateField );
```

So I want to pass a member expression to the Apply method, and have it apply an appropriate where clause to the result set, but I cannot figure out how to get the dateField member expression embedded in the *where* predicate's expression.  See lines "do not compile" in class above.  I need to transform dateField somehow or build the predicate expression some other way, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: You'll have to hand-craft `dateField >= BeginDate` using `Expression` class methods.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  I don't work with the Expression class itself much.  I've used LinqKit's PredicateBuilder, but it's not much help in this situation.  The final 'where' predicate must work in Linq-to-Entities too.

Comment: How's this look: `var expr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual( dateField.Body, Expression.Constant( BeginDate ) ); result = result.Where( Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( expr ) );`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to pass parameters to `Expression.Lambda`. Your code throws an exception when I try it. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 15):

What you're looking to do here is to compose expressions; you're trying to apply one expression to the result of another.  You can actually write a method to do that:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Compose<TSource, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TSource, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var intermediateValue = first.Body.ReplaceParameter(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var body = second.Body.ReplaceParameter(second.Parameters[0], intermediateValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(body, param);
}
```

It uses the following method to replace the parameter of an expression with an expression.

```
public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression,
    ParameterExpression toReplace,
    Expression newExpression)
{
    return new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression)
        .Visit(expression);
}
public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression from;
    private Expression to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : node;
    }
}
```

This allows you to write your code as:

```
public IQueryable<T> Apply<T>(IQueryable<T> source, 
    Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateField)
{
    var result = source;
    if (BeginDate.HasValue)
    {
        if (BeginInclusive)
            result = result.Where(dateField.Compose(date => date >= BeginDate));
        else
            result = result.Where(dateField.Compose(date => date > BeginDate));
    }
    if (EndDate.HasValue)
    {
        if (EndInclusive)
            result = result.Where(dateField.Compose(date => date <= EndDate));
        else
            result = result.Where(dateField.Compose(date => date < EndDate));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved me hour or even more on implementing it myself. It's a shame BCL doesn't provide this method

Comment: thanks for answer ! I'm getting a pretty poor performances tho. Exp.Compose(x=>x*-1) : Around 25ms. Any reason for that ?

Comment: Never mind.... I had a very long diagnostic session, restarting project gets me to around 2ms

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to hand-craft `dateField >= BeginDate` using Expression class methods.

```
(...)
    if (BeginInclusive)
    {
        var greaterOrEqual =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                    dateField.Body,
                    Expression.Constant(BeginDate)),
                dateField.Parameters);

        result = result.Where(greaterOrEqual);
    }
(...)
```

Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I came up with.  I'm going to post another answer with the final code too so people can just use it.  I just need to confirm it all works with Linq-to-Entities as expected.

Comment: I am trying using ``IEnumerable<T>`` for my own learning, but i am unable to have it compile, can you see what i  am misssing ?  ``public IEnumerable<T> Apply<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, DateTime, bool> dateField)
        {
            var result = source;
            return result.Where(x=>dateField(source,x));
        }``

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated Apply method created after figuring this out.

```
    public IQueryable<T> Apply<T>( IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T,DateTime>> dateField )
    {
        Expression predicate;
        if (BeginDate.HasValue)
        {
            if (BeginInclusive)
                predicate = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual( dateField.Body, Expression.Constant( BeginDate, typeof(DateTime) ) );
            else
                predicate = Expression.GreaterThan( dateField.Body, Expression.Constant( BeginDate, typeof(DateTime) ) );
            source = source.Where( Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( predicate ) );
        }
        if (EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            if (EndInclusive)
                predicate = Expression.LessThanOrEqual( dateField.Body, Expression.Constant( EndDate, typeof(DateTime) ) );
            else
                predicate = Expression.LessThan( dateField.Body, Expression.Constant( EndDate, typeof(DateTime) ) );
            source = source.Where( Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( predicate ) );
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Next, I'll transform it into an extension method, so it can be used like:

```
DateRange range;
IQueryable<T> q;
q = q.WhereInDateRange( range, x => x.DateField );
```