# Incorporate partial expression in LINQ/SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees, .net-5

I have an expression that returns a DateTime column in a query.

```
Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> GetDateExpression;

GetDateExpression = td => td.DateShipped;
```

But now I want to use that expression to form a filter in a SQL query.

```
query = query.Where(td => GetDateExpression(td) >= startDate);
```

But that won't compile.

> error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'DateFilter.GetDateExpression' cannot be used like a method.

Can anyone show me how to construct the where clause above using `GetDateExpression`?

Comment: Check this my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378438/can-i-reuse-code-for-selecting-a-custom-dto-object-for-a-child-property-with-ef/66386142#66386142

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Are you saying to use a third-party library for this? I'm not convinced at all that that's necessary. In fact, I'm pretty sure it's not. Although I don't know if I need to manually build the expression tree to make this work.

Comment: You have to write a method which constructs a `Lambda<Func<T, bool>` expression with body `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(yourGetDateExpression, valueOfStartDateExpression)` and you also should replace the parameter of `yourGetDateExpression`. Take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507906/how-can-i-include-one-expression-in-another-expression and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430996/replacing-the-parameter-name-in-the-body-of-an-expression and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736505/how-to-combine-two-lambdas.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo: Replace `yourGetDataExpression` with what? How can I incorporate the expression it contains?

Comment: Not the expression itself, but the parameter of it. See the thing, the `td` in your `GetDateExpression` and `td` in `Where` are different things, therefore you need to replace `td` of `GetDateExpression` with `td` of `Where`. As far as I know the replacement can be done with a kind of `expression visitor` which you can find following by the links I sent

Comment: @E.Shcherbo: Without the argument, it has no entity reference to get the column.

Comment: @JonathanWood, well probably our experience is different ;) EF Core itself won't parse such constructions.  For example with LINQKit you can call `GetDateExpression.Invoke(td)` and it will work inside `Where` condition. Don't afraid third party libraries they are very thin and plain for such easy task.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Well, I don't know about you but I've been programming since 1987 and I have some pretty strong opinions about how I like to approach things. This can be done in plain C#, so that would be my preference.

Comment: @JonathanWood, our experience is different, not sure that you have developed LINQ translator but i did.  Actually your question is closed and pointed to implementation that already done in third party libraries.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: No, I haven't developed a LINQ translator. Have you developed a custom language and interpreter written from scratch, or a full-fledged HTML parser? My point is I've been doing this a while. I'm not going to change my mind because someone tells me not to be *afraid* of third party libraries.

Comment: @JonathanWood, question is about LINQ. Just noticing that I have big experience in this area. I have also contributed into LINQKit - it is well tested and really small library. Anyway you can play with that by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method to construct a new `GreaterThanOrEqual` expression from two operands

The idea behind this is the following. You want to construct a new expression which looks like this:

```
td => td.DateShipped >= startDate.Value
```

using the body of your existing expression `td => td.DateShipped`, but important thing here is that `td` in the result expression and `td` in your `GetDateExpression` are different things, so if you just will write the greaterThanOrEqual expression without replacing you will get something like this:

```
td1 => td2.DateShipped >= startDate.Value
```

Therefore you need to replace `td2` with `td1` so that the expression looks like I wrote in the beginning. Therefore all the replacer does is replace each `ParameterExpression` it finds in the expression tree with our `filterParam`.

You can take a look at the following answers to read about this a bit more:

- [Why we need replacer in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6736535/8715436)
- [Implementation of `ParameterReplacer` used in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6736589/8715436)
- [Great answer with different solutions for different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5431309/8715436)

```cs
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> operand1, Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> operand2)
    {
        var filterParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var greaterThanOrEqual = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(operand1.Body, operand2.Body);
        greaterThanOrEqual = (BinaryExpression) new ParameterReplacer(filterParam).Visit(greaterThanOrEqual);
        
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(greaterThanOrEqual, filterParam);
    }
                                                                      
    internal class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
            return base.VisitParameter(_parameter);
        }

        internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter) {
            _parameter = parameter;
        }
    }
```

Then use it like

```
    Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> getDateExpression = m => m.Date;
    Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> combined = GreaterThanOrEqual(getDateExpression, td => startDate.Value);
    
    query = query.Where(combined);
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying to work through this now. Can I ask what `ParameterReplacer` is?

Comment: I updated my answer a bit with some info about this and with some additional links if it's not enough and more insight is needed.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Just FYI since EF Core 3.0 there is [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0) which can be used to perform the replacing task.

Comment: @GuruStron yeah thank you very much, this is useful to know

Comment: @E.Shcherbo also see my edit - no need to use html in your answer =)))

Comment: @GuruStron thank you for fixing this :) I used html to fix the format of the source code after I added list items for the links. See now how you did this elegantly with ```

Comment: @E.Shcherbo also links can be added easily with CTRL+L shortcut.